# Appending scripts in zend 2.3.5

Tags: html, zend-framework, google-analytics

For the past few hours I've been trying to add Google analytics to page.  I think I'm following the docs but it just doesn't work for me.

I'm trying to achieve:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=xxxx"></script>
  <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
      gtag('js', new Date());

      gtag('config', 'xxxx');
  </script>
```

I did:

```
<?php
    echo $this->headScript()            
            ->appendFile(
                'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=xxxx', 
                null, 
                array("async" => "true")
              )
            ->appendFile($this->basePath('/js/gtag.js'))
    ?>
```

.. but it doesn't work (and I don't think I can add gtag script like that.)

Result:

```
<script type="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-120611634-1"></script>
```

I also tried `appendScript`:

```
 ->appendScript("
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
            gtag('js', new Date());
    
            gtag('config', 'xxxx');
            ")
```

Result:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<!--
                window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
                function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
                gtag('js', new Date());
        
                gtag('config', 'xxxx');
    //-->
</script>
```

I have never dealt with Zend before but followed examples on the web and it just won't work.  I'd be grateful for any tips or help.

Comment: What is the issue? You want to add a script file and some inline script to the page. Your examples show exactly that result (you just need to combine them). Although personally I would just paste this code into the layout unless you only want it on certain pages.

Comment: I ca just paste it as is and its gonna work? If thats true I just wasted 3 hours